# How to target elements that have the same class without specifying the name of the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery so please forgive me if the question is too basic.

I know how to target two or more elements with the same class if **I know the name of the class**. My problem is that the name of many classes in the website I am building are created dynamically. So, I don't have much control about the specific name of the classes.

What I am trying to do is to target 2 elements **when** they have the same class **even if I don't know the name of the class** .

Ex:

```
<a href="#" class="title25">Some text</a>
<figcaption class="title25">Some text</figcaption>
```

So, when these elements have the same class (whatever it is) do something, when they don't do something else but without providing something like `.title25` in my jQuery.

Comment: Do you know the name of the element or not ? `a`, `figcaption` ?

Comment: Yes,`a` and `figcaption`are the elements I need to target.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$("a").each(function(index, element) {
    var class = $(element).attr("class");
    if(class.length > 2) {
       // do something
    }
});
```

Not tested..

Comment: Thank you:) I am going to try it out.

Comment: `class` is reserved, use another variable name

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting all `a` elements and for each of them, you look for `figcaption` with the same class

```
$("a").each(function() {
    // Here, 'this' is the current a element in the loop
    var currentClass = $(this).attr("class");
    // Search for a figcaption element with the same class
    var correspondingFigcaption = $('figcaption.' + currentClass);
    if(correspondingFigcaption.length > 0){
         // Here, 'this' is your a element
         // and correspondingFigcaption.get(0) is the first corresponding figcaption
    }
});
```

Of course, you can check that you obtain only one figcaption corresponding element but I let the full use to you.

Comment: would this work if the anchor elements had more than one class associated with them?

Comment: @BobNocraz If the anchor has more than one class, a figcaption need to have the same classes in the same order, in other words the exact same value for the class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Plain JavaScript:

- gather 2 NodeLists of anchors and captions with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- convert each NodeList to arrays with [`Array.prototype.slice.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- merge both arrays with [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- iterate through the merged array and on each iteration find the element's [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)
- then [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) (or [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) the `className` into a new array
- pass the new array through the function `findTwin()`
- `findTwin()`

  - loops through the length of the array and stores each element in an object to compare with the next element.
  - matches and singles are separated into an array of doubles and an array of uniques.
  - the array with doubles is returned and with a modification the array of singles could be used if desired.
  - The Snippet has a series of anchors and captions. There are 2 doubles: `title25` and `title00`.

**Snippet**

```js
var ancs = document.querySelectorAll('a');
var caps = document.querySelectorAll('figcaption');

var aArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(ancs);
var cArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(caps);

var mergedArray = aArray.concat(cArray);
var total = mergedArray.length;

var classArray =[];

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  var aClass = mergedArray[i].className;
  classArray.unshift(aClass);
}


var twins = findTwin(classArray);

console.log('matched: ' + twins);

function findTwin(arr) {
  var singleArray = [];
  var doubleArray = [];
  var total = arr.length;
  var sorted = {};

  while (total--) {
    var item = arr[total];

    if (!sorted[item]) {
      singleArray.unshift(item);
      sorted[item] = true;
    } else {
      doubleArray.unshift(item);
      sorted[item] = true;
    }
  }
  return doubleArray;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="title00">Some text</a>
<figcaption class="title05">Some text</figcaption>
<a href="#" class="title55">Some text</a>
<figcaption class="title27">Some text</figcaption>
<a href="#" class="title28">Some text</a>
<figcaption class="title85">Some text</figcaption>
<a href="#" class="title25">Some text</a>
<figcaption class="title25">Some text</figcaption>
<a href="#" class="title35">Some text</a>
<figcaption class="title00">Some text</figcaption>
<a href="#" class="title45">Some text</a>
<figcaption class="title26">Some text</figcaption>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and dedication in the answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved many ways. I would do that like -- asking for all types of class used in the page. Then accessing the elements using them in loops would have been easy. And that's subjective to what really you want to do with them.

**My code goes:**

```
<a href="#" class="title25">Some text1</a>
<figcaption class="title25">Some text2</figcaption>
<div class="title30">Some text3</div>
<span class="title30">Some text4</span>
<p class="title50">Some text5</p>
<ul class="title50">
  <li>Some text6</li>
</ul>
```

Here the example is shown with jQuery. You can also use raw javascript or any other frameworks.

```
var classes = [];
$('[class]').each(function(){
     $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
        if (this.length>0 && $.inArray(this.valueOf(), classes) === -1) {
            classes.push(this.valueOf());
        }    
    });
});

console.log(classes);

classes.forEach(function(i){
  $('.'+i+':first').attr("style", "color: red;");
  $('.'+i+':last').attr("style", "color: green;");

  $('DIV.'+i).attr("style", "font-size: 24px;");
  $('p.'+i).attr("style", "font-weight: 800;");
  $('span.'+i).attr("style", "text-decoration: underline;");
});
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/27g7aayt/1/

Comment: You are welcome! If that works can you please mark it as an answer. (y) :D